# My attempt at an immutable container view in C++

Tags: c++, immutability

I have this very simple template:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<class Container>
class ImmutableContainerView {
private:
    Container& my_container;
public:
    ImmutableContainerView(Container& container) :
    my_container {container} {}

    typename Container::const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return my_container.cbegin();
    }

    typename Container::const_iterator cend() const {
        return my_container.cend();
    }

    typename Container::const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const {
        return my_container.crbegin();
    }

    typename Container::const_reverse_iterator crend() const {
        return my_container.crend();
    }

    typename Container::size_type size() const {
        return my_container.size();
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return my_container.empty();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::initializer_list<int> il = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

    std::list<int>   my_list   = il;
    std::set<int>    my_set    = il;
    std::vector<int> my_vector = il;

    ImmutableContainerView<std::list<int>>   my_immutable_list(my_list);
    ImmutableContainerView<std::set<int>>    my_immutable_set(my_set);
    ImmutableContainerView<std::vector<int>> my_immutable_vector(my_vector);

    // Iterators:
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout, ", ");
    std::copy(my_immutable_list.cbegin(), my_immutable_list.cend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::copy(my_immutable_set.cbegin(), my_immutable_set.cend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::copy(my_immutable_vector.cbegin(), my_immutable_vector.cend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Reversed iterators:
    std::copy(my_immutable_list.crbegin(), my_immutable_list.crend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::copy(my_immutable_set.crbegin(), my_immutable_set.crend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::copy(my_immutable_vector.crbegin(), my_immutable_vector.crend(), out_it);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Size:
    std::cout << my_immutable_list.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << my_immutable_set.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << my_immutable_vector.size() << "\n";

    // Empty:
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << my_immutable_list.empty() << "\n";
    std::cout << my_immutable_set.empty() << "\n";
    std::cout << my_immutable_vector.empty() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to hear comments on how to improve it. In particular, is it possible to do some metaprogramming trickery such that it can adapt to different containers; for example, it could provide `operator[size_t]` for `std::vector`, but `find` for `std::set`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your view isn't immutable, though immutability might be a property of the underlying object. It's a constant view, meaning the underlying object might change, but not from that view. The canonical way to get a constant view is by the way to use a constant reference, unless the view should erase some of the differences between underlying containers, like [`std::string_view`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) does.

---

You are missing `.begin()`, `.end()`, `.rbegin()` and `.rend()`.

Your view is constant, fine, but forcing everyone to explicitly say so for each function-call breaks interface conventions.

The missing functions are the common interface, the ones you provided just optional convenience-functions for calling manually which might not be provided even if possible, and certainly never used in generic code. Take a look at [`<iterator>`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) and the free functions for accessing any generic range there.